# android phonegap SpeechRecognizer Cannot read property 'speechrecognizer

Tags: android, cordova

I am integrated https://github.com/poiuytrez/SpeechRecognizer

I got below error

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'speechrecognizer' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:20**

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Speech Recognition plugin demo</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="SpeechRecognizer.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>

            <script type="text/javascript">

                function onDeviceReady(){
                    console.log("Device is ready");
                }

                function recognizeSpeech() {
                    var maxMatches = 5;
                    var promptString = "Speak now"; // optional
                    var language = "en-US";                     // optional
                    window.plugins.speechrecognizer.startRecognize(function(result){
                        alert(result);
                    }, function(errorMessage){
                        console.log("Error message: " + errorMessage);
                    }, maxMatches, promptString, language);
                }

                // Show the list of the supported languages
                function getSupportedLanguages() {
                    window.plugins.speechrecognizer.getSupportedLanguages(function(languages){
                        // display the json array
                        alert(languages);
                    }, function(error){
                        alert("Could not retrieve the supported languages : " + error);
                    });
                }

                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
            </script>

            <button onclick="recognizeSpeech();">Start recognition</button>
            <button onclick="getSupportedLanguages();">Get Supported Languages</button>
        </body>
    </html>
```

config.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        id="com.phonegap.plugins.speech" version="1.0.0">
      <engines>
        <engine name="cordova" version=">=3.0.0" />
      </engines>

      <name>SpeechRecognizer</name>
      <description>Recognizes speech input</description>
      <license>MIT</license>

      <js-module src="SpeechRecognizer.js" name="SpeechRecognizer">
        <clobbers target="plugins.speechrecognizer" /> 
      </js-module>

      <platform name="android">
        <source-file src="SpeechRecognizer.java" target-dir="src/com/phonegap/plugins/speech" />
        <source-file src="LanguageDetailsChecker.java" target-dir="src/com/phonegap/plugins/speech" />

        <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
          <feature name="SpeechRecognizer" >
            <param name="android-package" value="com.phonegap.plugins.speech.SpeechRecognizer"/>
          </feature>
        </config-file>

      </platform>

    </plugin>
```

[image]

Comment: Is your  `console.log("Device is ready");` have been logged?

Comment: Where you have put your cordova.js file ? What is the location ?

Comment: see image in question

Comment: i am facing same issue. have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

just goto in command prompt at type:
cordova plugin add https://github.com/poiuytrez/SpeechRecognizer
than build your project & after that replace index.html code with above code which you write than simply run that project 
that's done.
I also work on that previous days and i successfully done that if you found any issue let me know

Thanks
Arun Sharma